# Proving that an injective function has an inverse

Tags: functions, proof-writing

My textbook defines inverses as follows.

> *f* and *g* are inverses of eachother if and only if
>
> 1. $f( g(x) )=x $ for all $x\in$ dom($g$)
> 2. $g( f(x) )=x $ for all $x\in$ dom($f$)

It then proceeds to state that $f$ has an inverse if and only if it is injective *(I am aware $f$ technically needs to be surjective as well but my course doesn't bother with that, and I know that any injective function can be made surjective by restricting the codomain)*, and I am trying to prove that. I have already proven that  ****injectivity $\Leftarrow$ invertibility**** as follows.

> Let $f$ be an invertible function. Then there exists a function $g$
> such that
>
> 1. $f( g(x) )=x $ for all $x\in$ dom($g$)
> 2. $g( f(x) )=x $ for all $x\in$ dom($f$)
>
> Let $a,b\in$dom($f$) such that $f(a)=f(b)$
>
> Then $a=g(f(a))=g(f(b))=b$

I now need to prove that **injectivity$\implies$invertibility**. Intuitively, it makes sense because if $f$ maps every element of the domain to a unique element in the codomain, then the mapping of every element of the codomain (restricted to image of $f$) to the domain must also be a function. I don't know how to mathematically prove this using the given definitions, and would appreciate any hint on how to go about it.

Comment: Indeed, if $f: A\to A$ in which $A$ is finite, so you have no job to do. So, you can exclude this case trivially.